# The begin and end tags are going in latex

Tags: tags, latex, equation

I'm trying to cut a long equation into two lines but the color of `\begin{split}` or `\begin{multiline}` are going into the equation tag.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{equation}
         \begin{split}
           & V_{k+1}(s) = max_a \mathbb{E} [R_{t+1}+ \gamma V_k (S+1) \vert S_t=s, 
            A_t=a] 
           & = max_a \sum_{s',r} p(s',r \vert s,a) [r + \gamma V_k(s')]
         \end{split}
       \end{equation}
```

Comment: A long equation*

Comment: Are you looking to write something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTGTK.png)?

Comment: yess exactly @Werner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `aligned` inside an `equation`. I've also updated some other inconsistencies.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    V_{k + 1}(s) &= \max_a \mathbb{E} \bigl[ R_{t + 1} + \gamma V_k(S + 1) \bigm\vert S_t = s, A_t = a \bigr] \\
                 &= \max_a \sum_{s', r} p(s', r \;\vert\; s, a) [r + \gamma V_k(s')]
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Werner thank you for your respond but my problem is that any begin or end between \begin{equation} and \end{equation} are green they are considered as an equation. I can't understand why.

Comment: @echtouka: Yeah, so? You're probably referring to the editor formatting; something that doesn't affect the output. Of course, I could be completely wrong and don't know what you mean.

Comment: Exactly, something related to the editor formatting, the tags between the equation tags are in green and it does affect the output. In other word I can't enter any other tags in the equation tags.

Comment: @echtouka: Without more information about the editor, how the output is affected by the editor, visuals of what's going on and what you mean by "tags", there's not much more I can do. You'll have to spoon feed me information since I don't know what's going on.